# Shell program, error in for loop. Variable not used

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I am quite new to shell scripting. 
My code should be very simple, quite a tutorial, but I cannot make it work:

```
case='Naca0012_pitch_V1'
for i in {0..800..10} 
do
    tec $case.$i.plt;
    cat tec.00* > $case.$i.dat;
done
```

The command `tec` generates some files that I need to concatenate.

What I obtain is:

```
Error opening file Naca0012_pitch_V1.{0..800..10}.plt
```

from the `tec` utility.

It seems that the code puts "{0..800..10}" instead of substituting the variable with one of the possible cases from the brace expansion.

Comment: Your code after in clause is not valid.

Comment: @Simonare Sorry, what do you mean? How can i fix it?

Comment: What is the shebang of your script, which shell are you using? You mention bash, but this is perfect valid bash.

Comment: It's perfect bash if you are on version 4.0+
Please verify your bash version with `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: In terminal, do  ls -l /bin/sh. Maybe your shell is /bin/dash ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to make use of brace expansion. Depending on the shell you are using, brace expansion is supported or not. Shells that do not support brace expansion are POSIX [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) and [dash](/questions/tagged/dash). Shells that do support braces expansion are [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) and [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh).

**Posix complient shells (`sh` or `dash`):**  If you want to mimick this kind of brace expansion in `sh` or `dash`, you have to do something like

```
for i in `seq 0 10 800`; do
  ...
done
```

**Disable brace expansion:** While [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) and [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) all support brace expansion, it is possible that it has been disabled. For [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) this can be done by executing the command

```
$ set +B
$ for i in {0..800..10}; do echo $i; done
{0..800..10}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I was using the wrong shell.

Answer (score -1):

Your loop ia not correct.

If your intention is looping from 0 to let say 800. Your loop is needed to be like

```
for n in $(seq 1 100)
do 
    #yourcode 
done
```

Comment: Sorry but your statement is wrong, the loop is perfectly valid.